# How to mock OWINContext for MVC 5 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, structuremap

I have a BaseController which all my controllers derive from, which sets a value (the user's nick name) in the ViewBag.  I've done this so that I can have access to that value in the layout without having to implicitly set it for every controller (if you'd just suggest a better way to do this, go ahead!).

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public BaseController()
    {
        InitialiseViewBag();
    }

    protected void InitialiseViewBag()
    {
        ApplicationUser user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        ViewBag.NickName = user?.NickName;
    }
}
```

I then derive that class, for example, in the HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IRoundRepository _repository = null;

    public HomeController(IRoundRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I've set up my controller's other dependency (the repository, used in another view not shown here) to come in on the constructor, and am using StructureMap for DI, and that's all working great WHEN I take out the line in the `BaseController` for getting the nick name.

The problem is when I include that line to get the nick name using the OWIN Context, my test fails with this

> System.InvalidOperationException: No owin.Environment item was found
>   in the context.

This is my test as of now:

```
[TestMethod]
public void HomeControllerSelectedIndexView()
{
    // Arrange
    HttpContext.Current = _context;
    var mockRoundRepo = new Mock<IRoundRepository>();
    HomeController controller = new HomeController(mockRoundRepo.Object);

    // Act
    ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

I think I understand WHY it's not working, but I can't work out how to get around it.

How should I be mocking/injecting/otherwise setting up this base controller so it can access the user's identity and not fall over during my testing?

Note: I'm quite new to using dependency injection, so if it's something obviously, or I'm going about this completely wrong, or leaving out any important information, I won't be surprised!

Comment: Your current design is tightly coupled to components that are not very easy to test. Mainly `HttpContext`. You are better off associating the nickname as a claim on the user principal when you authenticate your user. That way your controller don't even need to be concerned with the details of how to get it. And you can access it in your Views by simply accessing the User Principal. If you are using the default project template you can set the nickname claim in your AccountController when you do sign in.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at using Claims instead.  So is the lesson here that I should just avoid using ANYTHING in HttpContext or OWINContext if I can, to avoid testability issues?

Comment: Not that. I would say that let how easy it is to test something be an indicator of well the code to test is designed. think SOLID.

Comment: Thanks - and I got it working with the claim, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using claims, thanks to Nkosi for the suggestion.

In my `ApplicationUser.GenerateUserIdentityAsync()` method I added the claim to their identity:

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("NickName", this.NickName));
```

I added a helper extension method for accessing the `NickName` claim of an `Identity` object:

```
public static class IdentityExtensions
{
    public static string GetNickName(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirst("NickName");

        // Test for null to avoid issues during local testing
        return (claim != null) ? claim.Value : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Now in my views (or controllers) I can access the claim directly, for example:

```
<span class="nickname">@User.Identity.GetNickName()</span>
```